# Powershell access Denied

Tags: powershell

I've got this function, that move a directory to inside another directory, but always gives me the access denied error.

Any idea what am i doing wrong?

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts\MetadataExport -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    # this will look for a 4-12 digit number in the directory name
    If ($_.Name -match '(?:\b|\D)(\d{4,12})(?:\b|\D)') {
        $destPath = Join-Path $_.Parent.Fullname $Matches[1]

        If (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $destPath)) {
            New-Item $destPath -ItemType Directory
        }

        Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.Fullname -Destination $destPath -Force
    }
}
```

the error:

```
   Move-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Scripts\MetadataExport\kwakwala-rosenblum-0172' is denied.
   At C:\Users\User\Documents\ScripsPS1\MetadataExport.ps1:170 char:9
     Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.Fullname -Destination $destPath -Fo ...
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Scripts\Meta...-rosenblum-0172:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

[image]

So, the goal is to move every folder that part of the name matches with another folder with numeric name.

Ex:

[image]

The 'kwakwala-rosenblum-0172' folder needs to move to inside '0172' folder.
Just move if the Literal-Path is the same as folder's name.

Comment: There are two things which  I want to convey: 1) Access denied is simply the user through which ps is getting executed do not have the permission for that path to access. 2)Your main `if` statement should have the `else` block and the `not` condition should be part of the `else`.

Comment: @RanadipDutta His `if`-statements look fine, the `not` condition makes sense there and I don't see a need for an `else` block at all. Agreed that he should doublecheck permissions for the user running the script though.

Comment: @PMental: Sorry.. you are right.. Just saw the New-item statement inside the `-not` condition.

Comment: Thank you both! For your replies, but a think the problem is that it is the Move-Item cannot access the path, because it is used for another process. But i can´t figure it out., witch is. I`m running as admin.

Comment: Nothing in the script is causing anything like that, so if it's blocked by another process doing the procedure manually should also give you the error, does it?

Comment: @PMental, you right, manually there is no problem at all. No error or access denied message.

Comment: @iRon, thanks a lot for your suggestion. But no luck, still the same behavior.

Comment: You trying to move to an incorrect directory name: `C:\Scripts\Meta...-rosenblum-0172:DirectoryInfo`, probably because `$_.Name` is not a string but an `Object[]`, try: `If ([String]$_.Name -match '(?:\b|\D)(\d{4,12})(?:\b|\D)') { ...`

Comment: It's so annoying! There no reason for this behavior.

Comment: @iRon, yes. The $_.Name is just for match. The Move-Item has the $_.Fullpath

Comment: one cause of that sort of error is that you are causing the `G-CI` call to read things **_after they are changed_**. the solution is to wrap the `G-CI` call in parens to force it to read everything at once instead of grabbing things from a list that is constantly changing.

Comment: Yes, but it appears that it truthifies but doesn't (re)populate `$Matches`

Comment: @Lee, the idea is like this: (Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts\MetadataExport -Directory) | Foreach-Object {..} ?

Comment: Please see my update image. The idea is to move the kwakwala-rosenblum-0172 folder, to inside the 0172 folder. My G-CI call return precisely that both folders.

Comment: @Paulo - yes! wrapping the `G-CI` call in parens makes that call read the whole thing _one time_ and then send each item to the next pipeline stage. without the parens, the `G-CI` call reads one thing, sends that to the pipeline, and then reads the "next thing". when you change the source ... that can result in things getting read more than once ... or not at all.

Comment: @Lee, the error persists. It is possible that the folder i need to move be blocked by another process, like G-CI ?

Comment: @Paulo - once you have wrapped parens around the `G-CI` call, there ought not to be any more interaction with the source by that call. however, you _may_ be trying to move something before the rename finishes. ///// try to diagram out what happens to an entry at each stage of your process and determine where the possible contention may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but you effectively try to move a folder to a folder with the same name:

```
$Null = New-Item -Path .\0172 -ItemType Directory -Force
$Null = New-Item -Path .\kwakwala-rosenblum-0172 -ItemType Directory -Force
Get-ChildItem -Directory | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_.Name -Match '(?:\b|\D)(\d{4,12})(?:\b|\D)') {
        $destPath = Join-Path $_.Parent.Fullname $Matches[1]
        Write-Host $_.Fullname '-->' $destPath
    }
}
```

```
C:\..\0172 --> C:\..\0172
C:\..\kwakwala-rosenblum-0172 --> C:\..\0172
```

Which is the same as doing this:

```
Move-Item -LiteralPath .\0172 -Destination .\0172 -force
```

> Move-Item: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Meaning that this would likely "resolve" the issue:

```
if ($_.Fullname -ne $destPath) {
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.Fullname -Destination $destPath -Force
}
```

But, I am not sure what your expectation is.
You might want to explain (**in the question**) how you expect the subfolders to be (re)named.

Comment: thanks a lot, once again. Please see my update in question.